# fadeIn/fadeOut closest div when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with some optional fields that I don't want to be displayed unless the user specifically enables them. I am struggling to figure out the `.closest()` method in jQuery hoping for some guidance. There are multiple forms like this so I didn't want to us an #id for the sake of DRY.

```js
$('.enable-stage').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('.stage-dates').fadeIn("slow").toggleClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.stage-dates').fadeOut("slow").toggleClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stage">
  <h3>Stage Name</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="enable-stage"> Enable Stage</label>
  <div class="stage-dates hidden">
    <input type="date">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the general `if` statement is working because when using `console.log("checked")` and `console.log("unchecked")` inside the `if`, it works. I think I am mishandling the `.closest` method but I cannot figure out how/why.

Edit: for clarification, I'm trying to make it so when the checkbox is checked the closest `.stage-dates` div fades in and when it's unchecked it fades out.

Comment: have you tried using prev() and next() instead of closest?

Comment: @cup_of that ultimately became part of the solution, good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.closest()` returns the first ancestor of the selected element. It doesn't search the entire DOM and return the closest match. To use `$.closest()` here, we can find the closest `label` (since `label` is an ancestor to the checkbox), then use `$.next()` to target `.stage-dates`

```js
$('.enable-stage').change(function() {
  var $closest = $(this).closest('label').next('.stage-dates');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $closest.fadeIn("slow").toggleClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $closest.fadeOut("slow").toggleClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stage">
    <h3>Stage Name</h3>
    <label><input checked type="checkbox" class="enable-stage"> Enable Stage</label>
    <div class="stage-dates hidden">
        <input type="date">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. This worked perfectly, thank you. Thanks for explaining how the `.closest()` works. Is there a way to make it find the "closest" matching class if it's not an ancestor? I'm considering shifting this around as I move forward but I don't want to break it before I know the options there.

Comment: @crescentfresh no problem. You can always reference the jquery API to see what does what. https://api.jquery.com/closest/ There isn't some general "find an element" thing that will start crawling the page to find the closest element. Your best bet is just starting with a good selector that will help narrow down where things are, then use `$.find()`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, Michael! I need practice more but I think real projects might be the best way to run into this stuff! Thanks again!